# Higher IO performance in KVM guest

Tags: io, qemu, kvm

I set up a system with a KVM guest on it to test how the guest performance is in compare to the host. 
The system hardware specifications are as the followings:

- HDD: ATA SAMSUNG HD502HI
- CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i3 CPU
- Memory size: 8GB

I set 6GB of ram, 4 virtual cpu, and a disk image file with raw format, virtio interface, writethrough cache mode, and native io mode for the guest.

The OS is Ubuntu-14.04 64bits on the host and the guest (Kernel: 3.13.0-45-generic).

Then, I started with fio benchmark tool to benchmark disk io on both the host and the guest. You can see the results in the tables below (in the fio command the options size=512m and invalidate=1 were included):

**Bandwidth**

```
|       |   Random Read |   Random write|Seqential Read |Seqential write|
| Host  |   465347B/s   |   1199.7MB/s  |   107878KB/s  |   1434.2MB/s  |
| Guest |   46389KB/s   |   989223KB/s  |   1418.3MB/s  |   1096.4MB/s  |
```

**Iops**

```
|       |   Random Read |   Random write|Seqential Read |Seqential write|
| Host  |   113         |   306960      |   26969       |   367148      |
| Guest |   11597       |   247305      |   363080      |   280668      |
```

I also do a simple copy (file size = 564M) on the host and the guest and the result was almost the same.(Time in the host: 6.282s and Time in the guest: 6.352s).

I ran another benchmark in which 3,000,000 records were read from Mysql database and indexed into Elasticsearch. The result was unreasonable, because the job ran much faster in the guest.(Host time: 5m6.827s and Guest time: 2m19.469s).

I am really confused!
Why the guest IO performance is better in some tests?

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of possible reasons that spring to mind:

1. If you use writeback caching in KVM, you will sometimes see better I/O performance in the guest than on the host. This boost is similar to the I/O boost you'd see for installing a battery-backed write cache on a hardware RAID controller. The downside of writeback caching is that you risk disk corruption on power failure.
2. Benchmarks rely on accurate clocks. When you run a benchmark in a guest, you are putting a lot of faith in the reliability of the VM's clock. In your case, you're seeing several minutes' difference, which makes me think this probably isn't what's going on, but I mention it because it's something to be aware of when benchmarking VMs.